# Issue regarding KMS Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot, amazon-aurora

I'm using the tool created by aws at https://github.com/awslabs/aurora-snapshot-tool to copy aurora snapshots from one account to another account. However, I just don't understand what to enter for KmsKeySource & KmsKeyDestination while creating a destination account. I have checked the CMK pages mentioned on the site but still unable to understand. Could anyone give a clear explanation?

For KmsKeySource I have entered the CMK which my DB cluster is using in the Source account. Is it correct?

Comment: Are both the account in the same region or different.

Answer (score 0):

For aurora snapshot to be able to copy between accounts, you cannot use default AWS managed keys in KMS for at rest encryption, you need to create customer managed CMKs in KMS and use that CMK in your Aurora db at rest encryption. The KmsKeySource here means the kms cmk key id you use for source db, thats correct.

The KmsKeyDestination is only required if you are copying the snapshot between different AWS regions, as KMS CMKs are regional resources, you need to provide the destination region CMK key id if your source and target region are different. In such case AWS handling the copying of encrypted snapshot from region A to B, and re-encrypt it using region B's CMK.

If the source and target region are the same, then KmsKeyDestination is optional, as the target db can simply use the same CMK key as source, which is specified in KmsKeySource.